# Delete multiple columns from excel with epplus?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Is there a simple way to delete multiple excel columns in single line from code (C#), with Epplus?
I have a switch like this:

```
switch (packageId)
            {
                case 15:
                case 16: wsSheet.DeleteColumn(16);
                         wsSheet.DeleteColumn(17);
                         wsSheet.DeleteColumn(18);
                         wsSheet.DeleteColumn(19);
                         wsSheet.DeleteColumn(20);
                    break;
                case 17: delete multiple columns again..
                    break;
                ...and so on.....
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

...and since I have 15-20 cases to delete multiple (different) rows for each case, I would really like to shorten the code and time consumed by this method..

For the sake of clarity, package Id does not have any connections with column id. In real situation one package id is 358, next one is 469, and so on.. If I don't find smoother way, I will use loops with column indexes (which I'd like to avoid because in a single case I could end up with 5-6 loops eg. show first 15 columns, then remove next 4, then show next 5, then remove next 3,..and so on till the last column which has index 67)

**EDIT** (my solution for others that come to this question):
There's an overload of method DeleteColumn(fromCol, noOfCols), which deletes fixed number of columns which is supplied in 2nd parameter, but I wanted to have something like "delete all columns from column index to column index" so I wrote a simple small method that does it.

```
private void DeleteColumns(ExcelWorksheet wsSheet, int fromColumn, int toColumn)
        {
            for (int i = toColumn; i >= fromColumn; i--)
            {
                wsSheet.DeleteColumn(fromColumn);
            }
        }
```

It does the work for me in this case..

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clean code, you can do something like this (comments are in code):

```
//create dictionaty where id is packageId, and columns that should be deleted for that packageId
Dictionary<int, int[]> columnsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
//add values for each key
columnsDictionary.Add(358, new int[] { 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 });
columnsDictionary.Add(469, new int[] { 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 });
//etc...

//check if this packageId is in present as key in dictionary
if (!columnsDictionary.ContainsKey(packageId))
    return; //if not, exit or show some error...

//delete corresponding columns in one loop
foreach (int i in columnsDictionary[packageId])
{
    wsSheet.DeleteColumn(i);
}
```

Comment: For the sake of clarity, package Id does not have any connections with column id. In real situation one package id is 358, next one is 469, and so on..
If I don't find smoother way, I will use loops with column indexes (which I'd like to avoid because in a single case I could end up with 5-6 loops eg. show first 15 columns, then remove next 4, then show next 5, then remove next 3,..and so on till the last column which has index 67)

Comment: @NikolasSkurupatis Please, edit your question to clarify your question

Comment: thank you for quick reply, your idea sounds good and I will consider it if I get messed up. In the meanwhile, I decided to use overload of method DeleteColumn(indexFrom, indexTo), which will take few lines of code for each case, and will get the job done.

Comment: @NikolasSkurupatis that is probably the best solution. good luck